# string with a new line save in file in one line only

Tags: c++, string, file, newline, fwrite

I am writting a code in C++. And I have a string like this

```
std::string1 = "one 
                     two
                          end"
```

this string has got a 2 newline. I want to save this string in the one  line of file. for example:

```
std::string2 = "one\ntwo\nend"
```

End after I read from file this line and I change again string2 like a string1.

Do you know how I can do this??

My problem is to call the function to create a random strings and these strings maybe have got a newlines but I want to save and read from file the only one line. And this reason I don't know the string because it is random.

Comment: Don't try to do this, just write `std::string string1 = "one\ntwo\nend";` in first place. What problem are you _acually_  trying to resolve? Is it an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/)?

Comment: @MichaelWalz I edit my question please check it.

Comment: Well, your last edit completely changes the meaning of the question... but it's still not very clear. I'd delete this question and ask a completely new question with a clear problem statement. Best is if you provide a [MCVE], this howwver requires some work from you.

Comment: BTW `string2` __does__ contain two new lines.

Answer (score 1):

You can use raw string literals for this:

```
std::string1 myString = R"__(one
two
three)__";
```

The two underscores `__` work as delimiters which can be chosen freely. Use the same in the beginning and the end of the raw string literal.
Also notice that anything in between will become part of the string, including all whitespace characters.

Comment: thanks a lot!! But If the string1 has got the value already and I didn't know it.. how to get myString the string1 values??
like this: 'std::string myString = R"__(string1)__";'